# Possible to create case-insensitive HTML query?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to specify in a HTML query from a Google Spreadsheet not to be case sensitive?

For instance, I need to query all rows where column A contains the name "Jason". Since more people have access to the Spreadsheet and might insert Jason as "JASON" or "jason", the query will not filter these last two correctly.

Comment: "HTML query"? What does HTML have to do with this? Perhaps you meant SQL (the `query` syntax is based on SQL, though it's much much more limited).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `=upper()` function.

If you cannot use it in your HTML query, then add a helper column to your spreadsheet, and set it `=upper(A1)`   etc, and then query the helper column from the HTML query.

Comment: `lower()` will work just as well.

Comment: This is an acceptable work around for now.